# Add different unique labels to each panel in lattice

Tags: r, plot, label, lattice

It's quite clear [How to label panels in lattice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508269/how-to-label-panels-in-lattice) using `panel.text` or `ltext` arguments. However, what if I want to use a different, unique label for each panel in lattice? Let me illustrate my point with this simplified `Dotplot`:

```
library(Hmisc)
#example data
data <- data.frame(transport=rep(c("bicycle","bus"),each=2), 
                   att=rep(c("behaviour control","intention"),2),
                   value=c(4.134,4.5,3.77,2.4), Lo=c(3.92,4.37,3.51,2.2),
                   Hi=c(4.34,4.62,4.02,2.61))
#labels I want to use
labels.hi=c("likely","easy")
labels.lo=c("unlikely","difficult")
#example dotplot
png("test.png",width=300, height=400)
Dotplot(transport ~ Cbind(value, Lo, Hi) | att, data, col=1,
        panel = function(x, y,...) {
          panel.Dotplot(x, y,...)
          ltext(2.5,1.5, labels=labels.lo)
          ltext(4.5,1.5, labels=labels.hi)
        })
dev.off()
```

This code gives me the plot below:

[image]

The upper panel gets a correct labels ("unlikely" and "likely"), but the lower panel just gets duplicate of the upper panel labels. Instead, I want to plot the remaining labels ("easy", "difficult") in the lower panel, but in the same location as upper panel.

I know I could define each label separately using `ltext` argument for every label, but it's quite impractical solution considering that my 'real-life' plot (heh) has more panels, and much more different unique labels. Any suggestions? Lattice only please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Nice to see a good lattice question.) I don't agree with agstudy that subscripts would be a good indexing strategy. In this case they work by accident because your points are the same number as your labels and in the same order. Subscripts are that mechanism for picking individual data points for panels rather than a mechanism for indexing panels. Consider using the `packet.number()` or `panel.number()` functions. In this instance I believe they return the same values, but consult their shared help page if you have more complex conditioning factors in mind:

```
Dotplot(transport ~ Cbind(value, Lo, Hi) | att, data, col=1,
        panel = function(x, y,...) {
          panel.Dotplot(x, y,...)
          if(packet.number()==1){ ltext(c(2.5,4.5) ,1.5, labels= labels.lo)}
          if(packet.number()==2){ ltext(c(2.5,4.5) ,1.5, labels=labels.hi)}
        })
```

If you had your labels in a matrix it would have been easy to use indexing with "[".

```
lab.mat=matrix(c( labels.hi,labels.lo), 2)
lab.mat
#     [,1]     [,2]       
#[1,] "likely" "unlikely" 
#[2,] "easy"   "difficult"

png("test.png",width=300, height=400)
Dotplot(transport ~ Cbind(value, Lo, Hi) | att, data, col=1,
        panel = function(x, y,...) {
          panel.Dotplot(x, y,...)
          { ltext(c(2.5,4.5) ,1.5, labels= lab.mat[packet.number(),])}
        })
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, exactly. I had the same thought, though I'd tend to put the per-packet labels in a list to be indexed by `packet.number()`. With more than one conditioning variable, I might keep the labels in a `matrix(list())` or an `array(list())` object to be indexed by `which.packet()`.

Comment: I'm not sure I can yet appreciate the advantage of a matrix of lists over a matrix (or array) of character elements.

Comment: Not sure there *is* much advantage, though of course lists *would* be better if some packets differ in the number of interior labels they contain. But really, I was just narrating my thoughts and noting that although we had thought along very similar lines, there was a (slightly) alternative approach.

Comment: I'm convinced, especially if there were to be small text boxes to be filled with more complex contents.

Comment: Lists are so often nice for their general flexibility. With them, it also  wouldn't be too much work to pass in and use label-specific `gpar` directives, just to give another example.

Comment: Wasn't aware of `packet.number()` thanks for that. Every time I come back here I learn something new :) Also, the matrix approach actually works perfectly for me where I have much more labels like this - so much easier to organise this. Cheers @DWin.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for `subscripts` argument:

```
labels=c("likely","easy","unlikely","difficult")
#example dotplot
Dotplot(transport ~ Cbind(value, Lo, Hi) | att, data, col=1,
        panel = function(x, y,subscripts,...) {
          panel.Dotplot(x, y,...)
          ltext(c(2.5,4.5),1.5, labels[subscripts])
        })
```

[image]