# R lattice barchart: How to write the total sum on each bar in multiple panels?

Tags: r, label, bar-chart, lattice

I have a lattice bar chart with multiple panels and I would like to add the sum of each bar on top of the bars (e.g. `(70)` on top the of first bar on the top left, `(20)` on the second one, `(150)` on the third one etc.).

[image: Barchart]

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978024/adding-text-to-panels-in-lattice-barchart) here but I could not find a way to adapt that code for my plot. Unlike in that example, what I would like to do is to  add the 'total sum' of men and women on top of each bar vertical bar. I also could not label them separately using `ltext` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20126137/add-different-unique-labels-to-each-panel-in-lattice). Any suggestion, using `ltext` or any other way, would be very helpful.

```
civ1<-c("Single","Single","Marr","Marr","Single","Single","Marr","Marr","Single","Single","Marr","Marr","Single","Single","Marr","Marr")
Sex<-rep(c("women","men"),8)
Year<-rep(c(rep(1990,4),rep(2000,4)),2)
Type1<-c(rep("Traditional",8),rep("Dual-earner",8))
Earn1<-c(seq(10, 160, by = 10))
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(civ1,Sex,Year,Type1,Earn1))
df$Earn1<-as.numeric(levels(df$Earn1))[df$Earn1]

my.key<-list(space="bottom",text=list(c("Women","Men"),col=c("black","black")), columns=2,points=T,pch=15,col=c("darkgray","lightgray"),cex=0.8)
labels=c("70","20","150","110")


print(figure1<-barchart(Earn1~civ1|Year+Type1,df,groups=Sex, ylim=c(0,350),horizontal=F,col=c("darkgray","lightgray"),cex=0.8,ylab="Earnings",stack=T,layout=c(2,2),key=my.key,
par.settings = list(strip.background=list(col=c("white","lightyellow")),
panel=function(x,y,subscripts...){
    panel.grid(h=-1,v=0) 
    panel.barchart(...)
    ltext(1,200, labels[subscripts]) #not working!
    })))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see several problems. First, your `panel=` parameter is inside your `par.settings` parameter which is incorrect. It should be passed to `barchart` directly. Then you have some syntax problems with a missing comma and I'm not sure how your labels were intended to work with only 4 values. Anyway, the following code should work.

```
barchart(
    Earn1~civ1|Year+Type1,df,
    groups=Sex,
    ylim=c(0,350), cex=0.8, ylab="Earnings",
    horizontal=F, stack=T, layout=c(2,2),
    col=c("darkgray","lightgray"),
    key=my.key,
    par.settings = list(strip.background=list(col=c("white","lightyellow"))),
    panel=function(x,y,subscripts,...){
        panel.grid(h=-1,v=0) 
        panel.barchart(x,y,subscripts=subscripts,...)
        t <- aggregate(y~x, data.frame(x,y), FUN=sum)
        panel.text(t$x,t$y, labels=t$y, pos=3)
    }
)
```

Aside from fixing the problems described above, I've use `aggregate()` to calculate the total for each column and used those values to plot the text labels at the appropriate spot. The resulting plot is below

[image: resulting plot]