# Adding text to the tip of lines in xyplot{lattice}

Tags: r, lattice

I'm confused as how to add text in `xyplot`. Given the toy example below, I'd like to add the text `"A"`, `"B"`, `"C"` at the far right of the tips of `YA`, `YB`, and `YC`, respectively. I reformatted my data into a data.frame so it mimics my actual dataset. Any tips are greatly welcome

```
X = seq(1,100,length.out=5)
YA = 4*X + 10
YB = 2*X-5
YC = 0.5*X + 100

Xs = rep(X,3)
Y = c(YA,YB,YC)
index = as.factor(c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5),rep(3,5)))
Mat = data.frame(index,Xs,Y)
levels(Mat$index)=c("A","B","C")

xyplot(Y~Xs,data=Mat,group=index,col=c("blue","red","black"),type="l")
```

Comment: This should probably be marked as a duplicate question.  The answer to this question, [How to label panels in lattice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508269/how-to-label-panels-in-lattice), provides a solution.  You'll need to calculate the position of the end of each line, but that doesn't seem too difficult.  You may also be able to use the `text` function, as described in this answer: [How can i label points in this scatterplot?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13229546/how-can-i-label-points-in-this-scatterplot)

Comment: You're right. Thank you for pointing me to that link. It works now!

Comment: the `directlabels` package is often useful in such situations

Comment: http://www.magesblog.com/2014/02/adding-labels-within-lattice-panels-by.html explains an approach to your problem.